# openpyxl (2.4.8) trouble with background in style; always black

Tags: python, openpyxl

I recently switched my code to openpyxl to take advantage of the the ability to update workbooks and I'm having trouble with the background style.  I've tried a couple variations of the code below using both colors and the hex values and I always get the same results which is a black background and bold white text.  Thanks in advance!

```
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, PatternFill, Border, Side, 
Alignment, Protection, colors, Font

styl_hdg = NamedStyle(name="styl_hdg")

styl_hdg.font = Font(color=colors.WHITE, bold=True)
styl_hdg.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
styl_hdg.fill = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.DARKGREEN, fill_type="solid")

ws.cell(row=myrow, column=mycol).style = styl_hdg
```

I have also tried this because sometimes I get and error style already defined. When I go to add rows to an existing workbook/worksheet.

```
ws.cell(row=myrow, column=mycol).font = Font(bold=True,color=colors.WHITE)
    ws.cell(row=myrow, column=mycol).fill = 
PatternFill(fill_type="solid",bgColor=colors.DARKGREEN)
```

Answer (score 7):

From the OOXML specification:

> *This element is used to specify cell fill information for pattern and solid color cell fills. For solid cell fills (no pattern), fgColor is
>   used.*

So you need to set the `fgColor`

Comment: Thank-you; I was following other examples.

Comment: It's very intuitive but that's the specification. It's because a structured pattern fill has two colours with one over the other. Counterintuitively both are background colours with respect to cell contents.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pedroski55:
https://python-forum.io/Thread-Best-way-to-set-cell-background-colour-in-openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

xlsx = Workbook()

xlsx['Sheet']['A1'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FF001F', end_color='FF001F', 
fill_type = 'solid')
xlsx.save('some.xlsx')
```